# Force user to login with ssh key file

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I have disabled the passwordAuthentication in ssh and I can only access ssh using the .pem key file. But I can log in to ssh using

```
   ssh 'user@host'
```

I need to restrict a valid user login without the .pem key file or not able to login using the above command.
Kindly help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And your question is rather unclear too.

Comment: My question is, I can log in to ssh using the "ssh 'user@host'" command after adding my public key to the remote server. But I need to restrict login using this command. I always need to give the key file along with it. How can I achieve this? Kindly help me to achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have already disabled the passwordAuthetication, you can only connect via an authorized key. When you "ssh user@host" without the "-i path/key" it will try every possible method until it finds one that succeeds.

you probably have your pem file inside your .ssh directory, the system will try every key files stored there until one match or there aren't any keys left to try (in this case it will output an error)

tl:dr
if your key file is inside your .ssh dir, it will, automatically, try to use it

Comment: So I can restrict it by not placing my key file in the .ssh folder, right?

Comment: yes, if your key isn't inside .ssh folder you will have to especifficaly point to it using "ssh user@host -i path/key"